# Angular datetimpicker correct view

Tags: angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker. How can I only get this view:

[image]

And then the value of the selected day. Right now I try this:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date" ></datetimepicker>
```

But when I click it goes to another view. (days,hours etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the docs correctly try to set `minView: 'day'` in `data-datetimepicker-config`:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ minView: 'day' }"></datetimepicker>
```